# How does UITableView manage cells with variable height

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

How does UITableView manages cell with variable height? it asks for height of each and every cell/row on load, but moving further how does it "INTERNALLY"  ...

1. Calculate y origin of each and every cell. Calculating one after another is not an issue.
2. Decide which cell might be lying in a rect given some arbitrary contentOffset. What and how does it maintain its data structure to perform some fast calculation irrespective of number of rows in table view.
3. How does it manage addition and deletion of rows and update its data structure without much overhead .

Can someone shed light on this... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to be careful using cells with variable height, as it can be a performance problem. Your heightForRowAtIndexPath method can be called for cells that are not currently visible, which can be a very large number in tables with a lot of content. Calculating the origins works just like you imagine it would - it needs to know the heights of all cells above the one it's calculating the origin for.

Answer (score 0):

For cells editing you need to add this

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
}
```

When you perform the deletion operation it removes the content from the datasource array which you are using in the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method .